# How to enforce the condition depending on the class removed at one time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout, addclass

I have some problem. I need to add some class for specify element for a bit time. When this class is on live i want to execute one condition, but if is not execute another. Something is not right, can u help me? This is my code:

```
btn.live('click', function(e){
    info_board.addClass('animation_time');
    setTimeout(function(){
        info_board.removeClass('animation_time')
    }, 700);
    if (info_board.not('animation_time')){
        info_board.addClass('flying_info_board_out').removeClass('flying_info_board');
    }
    else if (info_board.hasClass('animation_time')){
        setTimeout(function(){
            info_board.addClass('flying_info_board_out').removeClass('flying_info_board');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (info_board.not('.animation_time')){ ` try to add a dot.

Comment: or change `if (info_board.not('animation_time')){` to `if (!info_board.hasClass('animation_time')){`

Comment: try changing `info_board.not('animation_time')` to `!info_board.hasClass('animation_time')`

Comment: and jQuery instance is always true. You need to check for its length.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Good point, I bet the OP was expecting `.not()` to return a boolean instead of a jQuery object. Either way, I think `.not()` shouldn't be used anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.not()`, you still need to use `.` selector to target a class. So use:

```
if (info_board.not('.animation_time').length > 0){
```

`.length` is needed because `.not()` returns a set of matched elements, which is a jQuery object with 0 or more items. But jQuery objects are always truthy in an `if` statement. So you need the right thing to check, which would be to check for how many matched elements were returned from `.not()` with the `.length` property.

At the same time, there's no reason to have `else if`...just use `else`.

Since `.hasClass()` is probably less processing for jQuery than `.not()`, you might as well use:

```
if (!info_board.hasClass("animation_time")) {
    // Your code from the if block
} else {
    // Your code from the else if block
}
```

Comment: i dont know why but it's not working, maybe bc i'm checking this at the same time as i'm adding this animation time?

Comment: it respond for a only one condition, or anyone :(

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski Well, you kind of have weird logic. You are removing the class, then immediately checking if it has the class or not (whether you use `.hasClass` or the right version of `.not`). The `setTimeout` executes asynchronously, 700ms later, so it really won't have any effect on the if/else part. Are you sure you don't mean for the if/else to be inside of the `setTimeout`? I know you kind of explained the scenario in your question, but you explain what you expect to happen more?

Comment: i need to execute this conditions when i'm clicking this button in this momenet when it has class animation time, so i think that this if/else need to be outside setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if (! info_board.hasClass('animation_time')){
```

The advantage of this is you can then store `animation_time` into a variable without having to use string concatenation to build up a class name:

```
btn.live('click', function(e){
    var animClass = 'animation_time';
    info_board.addClass(animClass );
    setTimeout(function(){
        info_board.removeClass(animClass)
    }, 700);
    if (!info_board.hasClass(animClass)){
        info_board.addClass('flying_info_board_out').removeClass('flying_info_board');
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            info_board.addClass('flying_info_board_out').removeClass('flying_info_board');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Storing it is no different. You could've easily stored it before and still used `.not()`. You just would've used `.not("." + animClass)`. And I don't think you need to reference the docs for `hasClass` - they are using it in the rest of their code...

Comment: @Ian right, but the code is cleaner if you don't have to rely on string concat to build the class name.  Also, it doesn't hurt to link to the docs for future visitors to this question.

Comment: Right, but you made it sound like only if you use `.hasClass`, THEN you can store "animation_time" in a variable. My point was that it was plenty possible beforehand. I'm sure you know that, I was just pointing out that it's not a effect of using `hasClass`